# Uniquely identify users on server with google id token

Tags: android, android-volley, google-signin

I am working on an Android application and I need to identify users on server. The app is about collecting some informations for different polls/surveys, so I need to uniquely identify users on server to make sure they answer one time only per question. I spent so many time on this project and I really want to make it as perfect I can. I read a lot of information about this, but I am still worried about some security issues.

Please help me to clarify some things:

- for now the entire app is done, but I integrated Google Sign-In. I am requesting the email:

  ```
  GoogleSignInOptions account = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
  .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
  .requestEmail()
  .build();
  ```

  and I'm sending it on server via Volley. On server side I condition user to answer one time only based on that email address. Everything works perfect, but I don't know if this is secure enough, maybe some "bad" users can send fake email address so they could cheat?
- I have also tried to get Google id token. I send it to server using Volley, I'm validating idToken on server, I'm getting email from there, and then condition user with that email address. Everything works fine, but I don't know if I manage it correctly because I have 3 activities: a login_activity, a main_activity where users can select the questions available, and an answer_activity, in which I collect information and send it to server. And I tranfer idToken between these activities with Intents, but I don't know if this is a good approach.

I've documented a lot before to ask these questions, I read a lot about authentication and many other things, but I don't know how to put things together.

Comment: I don't know of a way to reliably identify a person.  Email address is only a rough proxy, since more than one person could have access to an email address and a person can have multiple email addresses.  So a user could just sign in to your app with a different email address and take the survey again.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I think that this is not a big problem. My concern is if I decide to run the application with this scenario, can someone send to server big amounts of fake email addresses? If I take the email address with the requestEmail() can someone just bypass that and send fake emails to server? I mean if someone have 3-4 or maybe 10 even 20 different emails is not a big problem. But if in my code is a weakness and someone can easily send fake emails is a big problem. To be more explicit can someone manually send any string to server?

Comment: Yes, someone could flood your server either manually or with a script.  If the wrong person decided to attack you, you could get hit with millions of requests with fake emails from a botnet.  If you're concerned about it, I'd research how to protect yourself from distributed denial of service attacks.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking something like this may happen but I didn't know how to manage it... Thanks, I will take a look on that. But if I use the idToken, verify it on server, and take the email or UID from there. Is this safer?